# c# programmer tries for events in c++

Tags: c++

Hi all:  I'm an experienced c# programmer trying to do some work in c++, and I'm not sure about the right way to do this:

I am authoring a class that needs to notify a consuming class that something has happened.

If I were writing this in c#, I would define an event on my class.

No events in c++, so I am trying to figure out what is the correct way to do this.  I have thought about callback functions, but how do I handle a case where I want to execute a member function (not a static function).

More specifically, what I really need to do is to handle the event, but have access to member state within the object instance that is handling the event.

I have been looking at std::tr1:function, but I am having trouble getting it to work.

I don't suppose that anyone would want to translate the following example c# example into an example of the correct/best practice c++ (I need ANSI c++)? 
(please bear in mind that I have almost no c++ experience -- don't assume that I know any long-established c++ conventions -- I don't ;);

A simple c# console app (works on my machine):

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class EventSource
    {
        public event EventHandler<EchoEventArgs> EchoEvent;

        public void RaiseEvent(int echoId)
        {
            var echoEvent = this.EchoEvent;
            if (echoEvent != null)
                echoEvent(this, new EchoEventArgs() {EchoId = echoId});
        }
    }

    public class EchoEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public int EchoId { get; set; }
    }

    public class EventConsumer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public EventConsumer(EventSource source)
        {
            source.EchoEvent += OnEcho;
        }

        private void OnEcho(object sender, EchoEventArgs args)
        {
            // handle the echo, and use this.Id to prove that the correct instance data is present.
            Console.WriteLine("Echo!  My Id: {0}  Echo Id: {1}", this.Id, args.EchoId);
        }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var source = new EventSource();
            var consumer1 = new EventConsumer(source) { Id = 1 };
            var consumer2 = new EventConsumer(source) { Id = 2 };
            source.RaiseEvent(1);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [Boost Signals](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/signals.html).

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Are Boost Signals ANSI? (this code must compile on Windows and Unix).  Also, can you show me an example?

Comment: Yes, the code in Boost signals is quite portable. The page I linked to includes a [Document/View sample](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/signals/tutorial.html#id3195532).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic idea is to take function objects, e.g., something like `std::function<Signature>` as the callbacks. These aren't function pointers but can be called. The standard C++ library (for C++ 2011) contains a number of class and functions, e.g., `std::mem_fn()` and `std::bind()` which allow using functions, including member functions, to be used as function objects.

The part what is missing is something supporting multiple events be registered: `std::function<Signature>` represents one function. However, it is easy to put them, e.g., into a `std::vector<std::function<Signature>>`. What becomes more interesting (and requires variadic templates to be done easily) is creating an event class which encapsulates the abstraction of multiple events begin registered, potentially unregistered, and called.

Comment: ...and if you can't use C++11 (which would be a pity), [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0) can also provide you all these things.

Comment: @Dietmar  I'm having a hard time getting bind() to work with my instance members.  Could you show a code example?

Comment: @JMarsch: right now I can't test it but it looks something like this: `std::bind(&Class::member, &obj, _1, _2)` for binding a member function to produce a two parameter function. If the member function is overloaded, you unfortunately need to cast the member pointer to the correct pointer-to-member type to choise the correct one.

Comment: @Dietmar Thanks! -- I almost have it now. I have it working if I put the std::bind statement inside the event consumer (the class that will be called back). I would like to take this one step further. I would like to put a RegisterHandler() method on the event source, so that the developer using my source does not have to know the bind() syntax. Something like RegisterMyHandler(pointerToConsumerFunction, theConsumer) (those become the first 2 parameters to the bind. My problem is, I'm not sure how to express the types of those parameters. c# would be: (theDelegateType, object).

Comment: @JMarsch: Don't bother recreating `std::bind()` as part of you class's interface! This is what you'd end up doing: madness lies in this direction. Here is how your function would look like: `template <typename S, typename R, typename T0, typename T1, typename O> void RegisterMyHandler(R (S::*member)(T1, T2), O* o) { this->addHandler(std::bind(member, o, _1, _2)); }`. It's not worth it: users need to learn how to `bind()` functions anyway.

Answer (score 1):

C++ has a concept of functor: a callable object. You need to read about them.

Think about an object that has overwritten `operator()`. You pass an instance of such an object. After that you can call it like a regular function. And it can maintain a state.

Comment: What can collable-object do with event rising and handling?

Comment: @Desolator you use them to implement events and handlers. Kirill probably could have been more explicit about it.

Comment: @wjl, You are right. I addressed only part of the question. Only `I want to execute a member function`..

Answer (score 1):

There's also [Signals2](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/signals2.html) library in Boost, which provides an API very close to real C# events, at least in idiomatic sense.

Answer (score 1):

Qt has something that might help you called Signals and Slots: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html

It lets you specify what the signals (the events that you want to listen to) and the slots (the receiving side) an object has, and then you can connect them. More than one object can listen to a signal like you mention you needed.

Qt is a large app framework, so I'm not sure how to use only the signals & slots part of it. But if you're building an entire GUI application the rest of the Qt might benefit you too (a lot of the ui event stuff is based on signals and slots).